# how to enter html data into postgres database using nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, postgresql

[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KtHN.png)   [html form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvZtq.jpg)so i wanted to enter the data entered in the form to the postgres table using node.i already have tables made.i want the data to be updated into them using html form.so basically i want the values to be updated in the database after a transaction on the html form.

heres the code. the server.js file

```
const {Pool} = require('pg');
const express = require ('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const pool = new Pool({
user : 'postgres',
host : 'localhost',
database : 'postgres',
password : 'wasay123',
port : 5432,
})

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/web.html`));

app.post("/", function(request, response){ 
  //  pool.query('UPDATE "accounts" SET "balance" = "balance" - $1 WHERE "name" = $2', 
 // [amount,from]);
 //pool.query('UPDATE "accounts" SET "balance" = "balance" + $1 WHERE "name" = $2', 
//[amount, to]);
//console.log(request.body.data);  
response.send(request.body);  
console.log(request.body);   
}); 

app.listen(8084, () => console.log("Web server is listening.. on port 8080"))

start()

async function start() {
  await connect();
}
 async function connect() {
try {
    await pool.connect(); 
}
catch(e) {
    console.error(`Failed to connect ${e}`)
}
}
```

the html code is as follows the web.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
 ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #333;
 }

 li {
 float: left;
}

 display: block;
 color: white;
  text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
 background-color: #111;
}

 .active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
 }
  body {
  background-image: 
 url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree- 
  736885__480.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 }
 div {
 margin-top:100px;
 margin-left:500spx;
 }


  </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  <ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
   <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
 </ul>

 <div>
 <form action="/" method="POST">
  <label for="from">From:</label>
 <input type="text" id="from" name="from"><br><br>
<label for="to">To:</label>
 <input type="text" id="to" name="to"><br><br>
 <label for="amountt">Amount</label>
 <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount"><br><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">

 </form>
 </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

as you can see the queries dont work.

Answer (score 0):

You currently have no insert statement in your `app.post("/")` method. You can use a Promise to create and handle the query. Your function would look something like this..

```
 app.post("/", async (request, response) => {
  pool.insertQuery = (columnName) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pool.query(
        "INSERT INTO tableName (columnName) VALUES (?)",
        [columnName],
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) {
            return reject(error);
          }
          return resolve(result);
        }
      );
    });
  };
  pool.updateQuery = (columnName, column2) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pool.query(
        "UPDATE tableName SET columnName = ?, column2 = ? WHERE ...",
        [columnName, column2],
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) {
            return reject(error);
          }
          return resolve(result);
        }
      );
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: I want the data in the table to be updated everytime the form is submitted so shouldnt "update" statement be used here. also what should be values in the insert statement where you put a "?". that is where im facing the problem. i want the values to be the parameters of the form input.  the values need to be added to the table everytime i run that statement.

Comment: So in the insertQuery function you'll notice the parameter "columnName" these are placeholders for your variable/column names. The (?) is actually supposed to be there, it's what is known as a "PreparedStatement" which helps to avoid things like SQL injection. These parameters will most likely be "request.body.fieldName" from your form.

In terms of updating, you are correct that you would be using an `UPDATE` statement, however this is typically done _after_ the `INSERT` perhaps on a separate view.

Comment: You can see more about the use of PreparedStatements and escaping queries for the `mysql` npm package [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values)

Comment: I already have a few items in my table and don't want to add any new ones. But if i somehow do need the insert statement too ,what would the insert and also update statement look like based on my form placeholders? would be great if I could get that .

Comment: Although you technically are _able_ to do both statements in one query, it's not recommended as it creates security risks. The update query is very similar to an insert. I will edit my answer to show that. You will have to adjust the where clause.

Comment: so what would be the 'where' condition be to edit the values of my form elements "from","to" and "amountt" to specific columns in the table with "id","name" and "balance" columns . also i greatly appreciate the answers and explanation

Comment: i believe the update statement is going to be bit complex too since two values are needed to update once i.e balances of two people need to be updated in table when form is filled

Comment: You can update more than one value in a `UPDATE` statement. See some documentation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp). It seems your unfamiliar with SQL  AND Node/Express fundamentals and I would highly suggest you review those prior. The point is for you to _learn_, not have the answer handed to you.

Comment: i do agree i may lack much of the fundamentals but i am aware of the update statement. in my original post i have also shown the update statements which i have tried prior but to no avail. i dont think i have made it clear what i actually want and  the problem . so basically i want is like a transaction app. we enter names of two people in the html form with the amount to transact from one person to another. and i want this change to reflect on the database table aswell. the only step im stuck is at the update statement since idk how to connect the html entered values to databse table values

Comment: i have added the links pictures in the original post to make it more clear